# Assigning macros to mousebuttons 4 and 5 in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign macros to mousebuttons 4 and 5 inside Texstudio and would be glad for any help.

Currently they move the curser back and forth trough the last positions but I don't see that macro in "options" >> "configure Texstudio" >> "shortcuts" >> "editor" >> "basic shortcuts", where all other cursor macros are defined. So it might not be a Texstudio macro but a Windows one.

So far I've tried to assign macros to them with "MB4", "MOUSEBUTTON4", "mouse-4" and a few other versions but none work. Thanks in advance.